# Different Object Array Elements Refer to the Same Object?

Tags: java

I have an object array that I am using to store different objects. When I try to get the data from either object, it gives the last object's data. I made some new testing files and cut everything down to the problem itself. Here is what I mean:

```
public class Test
{
  public static ObjectTest[] objArray = new ObjectTest[2];

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    objArray[0] = new ObjectTest("Jimmy");
    objArray[1] = new ObjectTest("Terry");
    System.out.println(objArray[0].getName());
    System.out.println(objArray[1].getName());
  }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Terry
Terry
```

Here is ObjectTest.java as well:

```
public class ObjectTest
{
  private static String name;

  public ObjectTest(String nm)
  {
    name = nm;
  }

  public static String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }
}
```

What's making this print out the name for the last object? Aren't there supposed to be 2 different objects here? There seems to be only 1.

Comment: You have `name` set to `static`, so when you change it one object it changes in both.

Comment: There's only one `name`; you need an instance variable, not a class variable.

Comment: Moral of the story, don't just add on modifiers to things if you don't know what they do. Take some time to research and understand what is happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` is a static field here, it is just one for every instance of class `ObjectTest`. Delete `static` keywords everywhere.

Comment: That worked for me! Thank you so much! I get quite confused with the whole static thing. I'm leaning though.

Comment: No problem:)
Consider marking answer as correct / upvote so that everyone know, when having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables shared between all the class instances, the last value overrides everything you set before. Use instance variables instead of static:

```
public class Main {
    public static ObjectTest[] objArray = new ObjectTest[2];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        objArray[0] = new ObjectTest("Jimmy");
        objArray[1] = new ObjectTest("Terry");
        System.out.println(objArray[0].getName());
        System.out.println(objArray[1].getName());
    }
}

class ObjectTest {
    private String name;

    public ObjectTest(String nm) {
        name = nm;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Jimmy
Terry
```